# How to click on URL (focus should be on url) of the home page after successfully login in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How to click on URL (focus should be on URL) of the home page after successful login in Selenium?

```
WebElement url = driver.findElement(By.linkText("http://url"));
url.click();
```

But focus is not shown on the url of the page:

Getting error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to find element with link text == http://url

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: why you are using in http in link text

Comment: @iamsankalp89  same error without http also:

Comment: Share some HTML code so we can help you easily

Comment: what is the name of line displayed in page

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowldge you have to try with link text or partial link text, it is a general example

Using `linkText`

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
WebElement url = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"));
url.click();
```

Using `partialLinkText`

```
driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org");
WebElement linkEnglish = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("English"));
linkEnglish .click();
```

Comment: Please sahre URL or HTml for more accurate answer